# SQL exception not redirecting to .jsp page

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

In my catch block below for some reason is not redirecting with the output error message back to my jsp page.  The default tomcats Exception report instead shows up with HTTP Status 500.  And the error message shows correctly in the console window. But it's not showing the error message on the jsp page as stated below.  What am I missing?

register.jsp:

```
<p><font color="#ff0000"><c:out value="${status}"/></font></p>
<form action="<%=context%>/RegisterServlet" method='post'>
...
...
...
```

RegisterServlet:

```
   try (Statement st = con.createStatement()) {
            System.out.println(sql);
            st.executeUpdate(sql);

           } catch(SQLException sqle ) {
                System.out.println("Unable to register user: "+sqle.getMessage());
                //Check if we are getting duplicate key exception on userName
                if(sqle.getMessage().indexOf("Duplicate entry")!=-1) {
                    System.out.println("User already exists");
                    strUserMsg = "User name "+request.getParameter("userid")+" already " +
                            "exists. Please try another user name.";
                } else { //If other SQLException than dup key exception
                    strUserMsg = "Unable to register user "+request.getParameter("userid")+
                    ". Please try again later.";
                }
                setRequestAttributes(request);
                request.setAttribute("status", strUserMsg);
                rd.forward(request, response);
                response.sendRedirect("register.jsp");

            } catch(Exception e) {//If it goes into Exception other than SQLException
                System.out.println("Unable to register user: "+e.getMessage());
                strUserMsg = "Unable to register user "+request.getParameter("userid")
                +". Please try again later.";
                setRequestAttributes(request);
                request.setAttribute("status", strUserMsg);
                rd.forward(request, response);
                response.sendRedirect("register.jsp");

            }
```

Stack trace below:

```
exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:555)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.focus.servlets.RegisterServlet.doPost(RegisterServlet.java:113)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

root cause


Unable to register user: Duplicate entry 'test_user' for key 'PRIMARY'
User already exists
May 09, 2017 1:45:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
org.apache.jsp.common.register_jsp._jspService(register_jsp.java:227)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.focus.servlets.RegisterServlet.doPost(RegisterServlet.java:113)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: And what does the default exception say? Add the stacktrace to the question.

Comment: ok, I added the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure I completely understand, but if you catch the exception that is occurring the default handler for that exception (displaying it on the jsp) will be overridden and the app will continue to run.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out.  I had an error somewhere else in my code.  Completely different than what I just posted.